# Как сделать прокрутку блока, чтобы по достижению определенной отметки шел обратно

Tags: javascript, html, css, css3, html5

Уважаемые коллеги!
Только начинаю постигать изучение JS, так что не судите строго.
Сделал блок который двигается в правый край и хочу сделать, чтобы по достижению определенной точки менял свое направление в обратную сторону.
[ТЫК](https://jsfiddle.net/xb36g9u7/5/)

HTML

```
    <div id="test2"></div>
  <button id="stop">Stop</button>
  <p id="ouo"></p>
```

CSS

```
#test2 {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: gray;
}
#stop {
  width: 50px;
  height: 20px;
  margin: 20px auto;
}
```

JS

```
let sdvig = 0;
let timex; 
let test2 = document.getElementById('test2');
function move() {
  test2.style.marginLeft = sdvig + 'px';
  sdvig +=10;
  timex = setTimeout(move, 50);
  if (sdvig > 300) {
  sdvig = 0;
}
  } 
document.getElementById('stop').onclick = function() {
  clearInterval(timex);
}
let z = 0;
obr();
function obr() {
  document.getElementById('ouo').innerHTML = z;
  z--;
  if (z<-1) {
    clearTimeout(timer);
    move();
    }
    else {
    timer = setTimeout(obr, 1000);
  }
}
```

Comment: Исправил мелочи
https://jsfiddle.net/kaxtuy09/3/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Немного изменил ваш код добавив аргумент в функцию move... так нужно было?

```js
let sdvig = 0;
let timex; 
let test2 = document.getElementById('test2');

function move(a) {
  test2.style.marginLeft = sdvig + 'px';
  if (a) {
    sdvig +=10;
     if (sdvig > 300) {
       timex = setTimeout(function(){ move(false)}, 50);
     } else {
       timex = setTimeout(function(){ move(true)}, 50);
     }
    
  } else {
    sdvig -=10  
    if (sdvig == 0) {
     timex = setTimeout(function(){ move(true)}, 50);
    } else {
     timex = setTimeout(function(){ move(false)}, 50);
      
    }
  } 
}
document.getElementById('stop').onclick = function() {
  clearInterval(timex);
}
let z = 0;
obr();
function obr() {
  document.getElementById('ouo').innerHTML = z;
  z--;
  if (z<-1) {
    clearTimeout(timer);
    move(true);
  } else {
    timer = setTimeout(obr, 1000);
  }
}
```

```css
#test2 {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: gray;
}
#stop {
  width: 50px;
  height: 20px;
  margin: 20px auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="test2"></div>
  <button id="stop">Stop</button>
  <p id="ouo"></p>
```

Comment: Спасибо большое!
Оно!

Comment: @yeagorov отметьте пожалуйста полученный ответ как удовлетворительный